# Which solution is the right way to sanitize URL for <img> & <a href> tag in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am googling how to sanitize URL in GWT & found too many different ways to do it. I am quite confused & I couldn't make the decision.

So, suppose you have a textbox that allows user to enter html url & then you can wrap that url string inside  or  tag before insert it into DB. There is a table that have a column to store html code, like the following:

```
<a href=\"...\">AA</a>
<img src=\"http://xxxx\">
//more html rows  here
```

so suppose user enter `http://car.com/pic.gif`, and then after user clicks Submit button, I want to it to store in myDB as following:

```
<img src=\"http://car.com/pic.gif\">
```

But users can input anything so we have to make sure the url input are safe. So here is some options:

-Option1:

```
String str="http://car.com/pic.gif";
if(!UriUtils.isSafeUri(str)){
   String safeStrURI=UriUtils.sanitizeUri("<img src="+str+"><br/>");
   storeUrl(safeStrURI);// store html string into DB
}
```

-Option2:

```
    String str="http://car.com/pic.gif";
    SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    builder.appendHtmlConstant("<img src=");
    builder.appendEscaped(str);
    builder.appendHtmlConstant("><br/>");
    String safeStrURI=builder.toString();
    storeUrl(safeStrURI);// store html string into DB
```

-Option3:

```
String str="http://car.com/pic.gif";
String safeStrURI="<img src="+UriUtils.fromString(str).asString()+"><br/>";
storeUrl(safeStrURI);// store html string into DB
```

/..... there are some more solutions but i don't know

I don't understand why Google don't just make 1 or 2 methods for achive this, why there are so many ways to do that made me very **confused**.

So, which option is good for solving my problem.

Or do you know other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1 is broken. `sanitizeUri` should be applied on `str` before it's concatenated with the HTML bits. That makes it more or less equivalent to option 3, modulo the call to `isSafeUri`.
- Option 2 would be unsafe and will actually fail because of the values passed to `appendHtmlConstant` (see the [javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlBuilder.html#appendHtmlConstant%28java.lang.String%29))

IMO, you should check first for `isSafeUri`, then, to be really safe, you should concatenate values but making sure you generate valid HTML (e.g. a `"` or `'` in the value won't close your attribute value). For that you have `SafeHtml` but it only works at the *element* level; if you need to go deeper (at the *attribute* level), then you have [`SafeHtmlTemplates`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html) (note that it can only be used in client-side code, contrary to `SafeHtml` and `SafeUri`)

```java
interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
  @Template("<img src=\"{0}\">")
  SafeHtml img(SafeUri uri);
}

static final Templates TEMPLATE = GWT.create(Templates.class);

if (UriUtils.isSafeUri(str)) {
  String img = TEMPLATE.img(UriUtils.fromString(str)).asString();
  store(img);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but just wondering. Do i need to check "String img" at the server level ? What if at client level we sure "String img" but when passing to server somehow img got altered? But I am using GWTP & i set up SecurityCookie so do i still need to check at server level?

Comment: so you mean "SafeHtmlTemplates" can only be used in client-side code? can u explain this further?

Comment: or do u think this way better, store str="http://car.com/pic.gif" into 1 column & there's another column mark it as image. When we show it to the user myHtml=SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant(TEMPLATE.img(UriUtils.fromString(str)).asString());

Comment: `SafeHtmlTemplates` relies on code generation by a GWT generator (`GWT.create()`), so it won't work outside a GWT environment (e.g. server side). On the server side (and client side), you should be able to use `"<img src=\"" + SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape(UriUtils.sanitizeUri(str)) + "\">"`

Comment: But generally speaking, yes, I think it's safer to avoid storing HTML.